# While loop with variable assignment

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop, tcpserver

How does a while loop with a variable assignment work? Here is an example that I saw.

```
require "socket"
server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 4567)
loop do
    socket = server.accept
    headers = {}
    while line = socket.gets.split(' ', 2) # Here is the var assignment in loop
        break if line[0] == ""
        headers[line[0].chop] = line[1].strip
    end
    data = socket.read(headers["Content-Length"].to_i)
end
```

I understand everything except the line 5-10 stretch. Just a step by step guide to how it is being executed would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment expression have values.

```
line = socket.gets.split(' ', 2)
```

The value of the right hand side is assigned to the left hand side, and then the value of the right hand side is returned as the value of the assignment expression.

```
while line = socket.gets.split(' ', 2)
```

The value of `socket.gets.split(' ', 2)` is used as the condition. However, in this example, the condition is always true because [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-split) will never return `nil` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves part of my confusion. I added a bit more to my question to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

The code fires up a TCP server listening on port 4567, listens for incoming traffic, when any traffic comes in it tears apart the headers which appear to be coming in as a string and maps them out to a hash, then it reads the document coming in based on the value of a specific header.

Lines 5-10 broken down:

```
headers = {}
```

This sets headers to a blank hash (a la Hash.new) in the scope of the main loop, allowing you to set it to a value within the while beginning on the next line and then access it after the while exits.

```
while line = socket.gets.split(' ', 2) # Here is the var assignment in loop
```

This begins your while loop.  The block gets executed if the while condition evaluates to `true`.  As Yu mentioned, the right hand side of the assignment is returned as the value of the assignment expression, meaning the result of `socket.gets.split(' ',2)` is evaluated for truthiness.  This will always evaluate as `true`.  The result of the operation is then set to the variable `line` within the scope of the `while`.

```
    break if line[0] == ""
```

If the first element of `line` is equal to "", we will exit the `while` loop.  This is the same as writing `break if line.first.empty?`

```
    headers[line[0].chop] = line[1].strip
```

Provided the previous line didn't evaluate to true, we proceed to setting the key in the `headers` hash named whatever the value of `line[0].chop` turns out to be to the value contained in `line[1].strip`.  Chop and strip are string cleanup methods.

If `line` had been set to `['foo','bar']`, this would merge `{'foo' => 'bar'}` into `headers`.

```
end
```

This ends the `while` loop.

```
data = socket.read(headers["Content-Length"].to_i)
```

This sets the variable `data` to the value of what `socket.read(integer)` would return.  Given it's the content length header, I assume that would return the entire document read by the socket.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, hopefully it well help others who have the same question (I'm a bit past this problem now, but +1 for a good answer anyways). Out of curiosity, how'd you find this question? It's been 3 years since I asked it.

Comment: Stumbled across it while searching about syntax and best-practices for defining variables within a test in Ruby, saw that it wasn't actually answered.  Figured it could only help anyone else stumbling across it in the future.

Comment: Well, thank you for answering! I hope you stick around here on SO (or on any of the other [network sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)) :)